# Setting a function as a ng-model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a complex structure of data (products of a shopping cart), like this:

```
items = [
    {
        id_product: 5,
        combinations: [
            {
                id_product_attribute: 35,
                quantity: 1,
                price: 25.60
            },
            {
                id_product_attribute: 38,
                quantity: 4,
                price: 25.60
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id_product: 5,
        combinations: [
            {
                id_product_attribute: 35,
                quantity: 1,
                price: 28.60
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I also have a `ng-repeat` that lists, in a `li` elements, every combination of a product retrieved from a `$resource`. Each `li` element looks like this:

```
<li>Combination {{ combination.id }} - Price {{ combination.price }} - In your shopping cart {{ function_goes_here(product.id, combination.id) }}</li>
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to write some kind of function that would search in the shopping cart data structure (by product id and combination id) and return the quantity element, in a such way that would update the view if another combination of the same type is added to the shopping cart?

Comment: not enough information given for us to help you make a connection to another data source. Suggest you create a demo

Comment: @charlietfl What information are you missing? IMHO you have all the information needed for the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your $scope/scope define that function:

```
$scope.items = [
    {
        id_product: 5,
        combinations: [
            {
                id_product_attribute: 35,
                quantity: 1,
                price: 25.60
            },
            {
                id_product_attribute: 38,
                quantity: 4,
                price: 25.60
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id_product: 5,
        combinations: [
            {
                id_product_attribute: 35,
                quantity: 1,
                price: 28.60
            }
        ]
    }
];

$scope.function_goes_here = function(productId, combinationId){
    //search through $scope.items
    return "Lorem Ipsum";
}
```

Comment: In general, this is right. However, I wonder if a function is the right solution for this. You lose a lot of the structure and style (and benefits) of the 2-way binding. Why would you do it this way, and not have the resultant information kept on the scope?

Comment: Would that actually update the view if another item is added to the data structure?

Comment: @deitch I'm open to suggestions

Comment: @alexandernst throw up a jsfiddle, let's mess around with it there. I think calculating logic like that should be run out of the controller. Data presentation to the view should be via two-way bindings on scope objects, whereas changes should be either UI driven changes on scope objects, or if they drive activity then call functions. Either way, throw up a fiddle, happy to look at it.